# How to use having in this query

Tags: mysql, sql

**How to use having in this query?**

I wrote a query, for trending posts.

```
SELECT * 
FROM auteurs 
    INNER JOIN posts ON auteurs.id = posts.auteur_id
```

this works, but it should only show the post with more then 10 likes, when i add having in the query like this `HAVING COUNT likes > 10` it wont work but i must use Having in the query. So the end result has to be, that it will display only authors who have in total more then 10 likes.

***Import.sql***

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.1.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Gegenereerd op: 02 nov 2021 om 10:32
-- Serverversie: 10.4.14-MariaDB
-- PHP-versie: 7.4.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `foodblog`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `auteurs`
--

CREATE TABLE `auteurs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `auteur` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `auteurs`
--

INSERT INTO `auteurs` (`id`, `auteur`) VALUES
(1, 'Mounir Toub'),
(2, 'Miljuschka'),
(3, 'Wim Ballieu');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `posts`
--

CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titel` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datum` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `img_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inhoud` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `auteur_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Gegevens worden geëxporteerd voor tabel `posts`
--

INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `titel`, `datum`, `img_url`, `inhoud`, `auteur_id`, `likes`) VALUES
(1, 'Pindakaas', '2020-06-18 13:25:00', 'https://i.ibb.co/C0Lb7R1/pindakaas.jpg', 'Verwarm de oven voor op 180 °C. Verdeel de pinda’s over een met bakpapier beklede bakplaat en rooster in ca. 8 min. lichtbruin. Schep regelmatig om. Maal de warme pinda’s in de keukenmachine in 4 min. tot een grove, dikke pindakaas. Schep de rand van de kom regelmatig schoon met een spatel. Voeg het zout, de olie en honing toe en maal nog 1 min. tot een gladde pindakaas. Schep in een pot en sluit af.\n        variatietip: Houd je van pindakaas met een smaakje? Voeg dan na de honing 1 el sambal badjak, 1 tl gemalen kaneel of 1 el fijngehakte pure chocolade toe. bewaartip: Je kunt de pindakaas 3 weken in de koelkast bewaren.', 1, 15),
(2, 'Baklava', '2020-03-11 10:28:00', 'https://i.ibb.co/ZWVRdPT/baklava.jpg', 'Voorbereiding\n\n    Verwarm de oven voor op 190 °C. Vet de bakvorm in met roomboter.\n    Smelt de roomboter in een pannetje. Snijd het baklavadeeg op dezelfde breedte als de bakvorm en bewaar het in een schone droge keukendoek om uitdrogen te voorkomen. Verwarm in een pan 300 gr honing met 20 ml oranjebloesemwater en houd dit mengsel warm. Roer in een mengkom de gezouten roomboter, 500 g gemalen walnoten, de rest van de honing en het oranjebloesemwater en de kaneel door elkaar. Verdeel het mengsel in zeven gelijke porties (van circa 90 g).\n\n    Bereiding\n    Bestrijk een vel baklavadeeg met gesmolten roomboter. Leg er een tweede vel op en bestrijk dat ook. Neem één portie van het walnotenmengsel en verdeel dat onderaan over het baklavadeeg. Rol op tot een staaf, leg deze in de bakvorm en bestrijk met gesmolten roomboter. Maak de rest van de staven op dezelfde manier.\n    Snijd elke staaf met een scherp mes meteen in zessen. Bak de baklava in circa 25 minuten goudbruin en krokant in de oven.\n    Neem de bakvorm uit de oven en verdeel de warme honing over de baklava. Garneer meteen met de rest van de fijngemalen walnoten. Laat de baklava minimaal 3 uur afkoelen voordat je ervan gaat genieten.', 2, 34),
(14, 'Bit Academy', '2021-10-29 14:38:22', 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/uQDOFbTNU-4/maxresdefault.jpg', 'MOunirrr', 3, 1);

--
-- Indexen voor geëxporteerde tabellen
--

--
-- Indexen voor tabel `auteurs`
--
ALTER TABLE `auteurs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexen voor tabel `posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `auteur_id` (`auteur_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT voor geëxporteerde tabellen
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT voor een tabel `auteurs`
--
ALTER TABLE `auteurs`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT voor een tabel `posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `posts`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=15;

--
-- Beperkingen voor geëxporteerde tabellen
--

--
-- Beperkingen voor tabel `posts`
--
ALTER TABLE `posts`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`auteur_id`) REFERENCES `auteurs` (`id`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: HAVING required GROUP BY-clause

Comment: You're wrong using HAVING, you need: WHERE likes > 10

Comment: ___only show the post with more then 10 likes___ So WHERE are you keeping the Likes count??

Comment: *when i add having in the query like this `HAVING COUNT likes > 10` it wont work but i must use Having in the query* Remove `COUNT` word... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7169faf7977a236e2b16ecb19a871b1f

Comment: @Sergey MySQL allows to use HAVING without GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `where` condition to filter the records with more than 10 likes, based on your tables and data records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM auteurs 
INNER JOIN posts ON auteurs.id = posts.auteur_id    
WHERE  likes > 10;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qff694udysNgqbyJyFcDzn/0

Comment: OP tells *but i must use Having in the query* - maybe this is a homework with this strange condition simply?

Comment: @Akina maybe, but I think we should point  to the right way

Comment: A working query may not be a correct query! Given that, HAVING filters GROUPs  whereas WHERE filters Table rows. If you are not grouping, the entire table is a degenerate group!

Comment: Yeah, i understand but we obligated to use HAVING, but i also thought that WHERE was way better to use!

Comment: @RaviTiwari you are correct but  based on the `OP` data examples it saves the likes in one row that's why I am using where not having

Comment: @RaviTiwari *Given that, HAVING filters GROUPs whereas WHERE filters Table rows. If you are not grouping, the entire table is a degenerate group!* This is not correct. HAVING without GROUP BY allows to refer to the output column alias and do not repeat the output column expression which can be so complex that the server does not distinguish its identity and hence will calculate the value twice.

Answer (score 0):

`Posts` Table has `likes` and its likes count. So, filter posts with more than 10 likes (or whatever the predicate is). Once done, join with Author to get author details as well.

```sql
select * from author as a 
inner join 
(select * from posts where likes > 10) as p
on a.id = p.author_id
```